Convexity and subdifferential monotonicity
Do you know any reference where I can find some results in this sense:
Consider $W:K\to [0,\infty)$ is a functional defined on a convex cone $K\subset X$, where $X$ is a Banach space. Then the convexity of $W$ is equivalent to the monotonicity of its set-valued subdifferential $\partial W$.
I saw this assertion in this article https://www.researchgate.net/publication/321069893_A_px-version_of_Diaz-Saa_Inequality_and_some_applications (at page 3). Here it is a print-screen:



So, I am interested in sources that deal with functionals defined on cones (not on the entire space), and if they link subdifferentiability with Gateaux differentiability then it would be awesome.

Many books on convex analysis define convex function mapping into $]-∞,∞]$ and define the effective domain of the function as the set where it has finite values. In this contact the claim is also true, so I am not really sure what the question is.

I think that the answer depends crucially on the definition of "subdifferential". If we take the standard definition $\partial W(x) = { u \mid \forall y \in K : W(y) \ge W(x) + \langle u, y - x \rangle}$, then the answer is "no". Take $K = [0, \infty) \subset \mathbb R$ and $W(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Then, the subdifferential is empty everywhere (up to the origin) and, consequently, the subdifferential mapping is monotone.
